# How can i grab one of my elements in the array and style it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi devs im learning React and i want to know if there's a method to grab an element from my array
and style it with css.

```
const card = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "DEEP EARTH",
    Background: "images/earth.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "NIGHT ARCADE",
    Background: "images/arcade.jpg",

  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "SOCCER TEAM VR",
    Background: "images/soccer.jpg",
  }
]
```

Comment: What element? JavaScript objects can't be styled by CSS

Answer (score 0):

You will need to render this using map, and then you could apply any css you want with it.
this might help:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

you could add a property to the ones you want styled:

```
const card = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "DEEP EARTH",
        Background: "images/earth.jpg",
        style: {"color": "red"}
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "NIGHT ARCADE",
        Background: "images/arcade.jpg",

     },
 ];
```

and then use map:

```
{
  card.map((cardItem, index) => {
    return <div>
      <span style={cardItem.style}>{cardItem.title}</span>
    </div>
  })
}
```

and in the same manner you could have that property point to a css class you have defined and use className.

Comment: i map through the array to create 3 cards,  but i want to just style one of the elements, sorry if i didn't  make it clear.

Comment: @Arturo You could just use a simple if(item.id == "something") to return a div with or without the style tag

Comment: agree, or you could have the css as a property in the object. i'll edit the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

As early was said you can use map and inline styles

```
  return (<div>
{card.map((item) => (
    <div key={item.id}>{item.title} 
       styles={{background:url(item.src)}}
     >
</div>
))}
</div>);
```